# Removing specific values XML but keeping tag names using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I want to remove specific values from my XML but keep the tag names.  I've seen examples that do the opposite (remove tags but keep values).  Here is my XML:

```
<Result>
    <Max>100</Max>
    <Min>10</Min>
    <Range>90</Range>
    <ResultPoints>
        <ResultP1>.</ResultP1>
    <ResultP2>.</ResultP2>
    <ResultP3>.</ResultP3>
    <ResultP4>.</ResultP4>
    <ResultP5>.</ResultP5>
    </ResultPoints>
</Result>
```

I want to remove the '.' but keep the tag names so my XML will look like this:

```
<Result>
    <Max>100</Max>
    <Min>10</Min>
    <Range>90</Range>
    <ResultPoints>
    <ResultP1/>
    <ResultP2/>
    <ResultP3/>
    <ResultP4/>
    <ResultP5/>
    </ResultPoints>
</Result>
```

Here is my XLT.  This completely removes the ResultPn tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[. = '.']">
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do an `xsl:copy` in your template, to copy across the element you have matched. Note you don't really need to output an empty string here either.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[. = '.']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, I added an `xsl:apply-templates` to copy across any existing attributes.

Alternatively, you could replace the second template with this one instead (which matches the text node directly, rather than the parent element)

```
 <xsl:template match="text()[. = '.']" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim!  That is exactly what I was looking for!